# Javax persistence change IDENTITY to SEQUENCE on production level

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, sequence-generators, jpa

Is it possible to change id generation from `GenerationType.IDENTITY` to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` without pain for a production version of a service? DBMS is PostgreSQL.

I need to switch to `SEQUENCE` in order to allow Hibernate execute batch operations. But my production service had a `IDENTITY` strategy for about one year. Will the change in Entity class somehow affect the previously generated IDs?

Now I have

```
@Entity 
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"}, callSuper = false)
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long id;

}
```

What will happen if I will change the strategy to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` should not be an issue as long as you make sure that the sequence starts at a value that's higher than any existing value in the `id` column.